# EditItemTemplate in FormView Won't Show (Using AJAX Controls TabPanels and VB/ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, .net, formview

I'm doing some work for a co-op/internship job and I can't seem to get this to work:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="AJAXScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="NewAppTabs" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Height="500px"
    Width="968px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small">
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Application" ID="ApplicationInformation">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:FormView ID="ApplicationInformationForm" runat="server" Width="950px" BackColor="#F7F6F3"
                Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" DefaultMode="Insert">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ReadOnly
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    Insert
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    Edit
                </EditItemTemplate>

            </asp:FormView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Tab 2" ID="TabPanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Tab 3" ID="TabPanel2">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Tab 4" ID="TabPanel3">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

For some reason when I set the DefaultMode of the FormView to anything other than InsertMode nothing is displayed.

I was just wondering if there was anyone who could help me out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Updated code. I also want to note that if I specify the attribute as DefaultMode="Insert", then it works, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: you might want to take a quick peek at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.defaultmode.aspx.  and since you may want a item template as well.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and I assume that I am using it right. Unfortunately I have just learned ALOT of new VB, and .NET within the last month. I use a MsgBox() to tell me the mode it is in after i set it. This has the correct value, but there is no text in the TabPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly fine. It was some other VB code in the background that was changing it without me knowing. Oh the wonders of inheriting projects...